# Report as data source for Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, reporting

Is there a way to to access summary info (I do not want draw a report chart )  in visualforce page?

Background:

I want to manage a summary report in the background and expose only the summary  totals and pass it to the vf page. The idea is to prevent code change every time there is a change to the filter criteria by maintaining a report that runs as a background for the columns in the VF page.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

Tooling API comes to mind if you can live with a callout to the report on every access (you could maybe cache that page).

Straightforward `Page.getContent('/reportId?excel=1&details=no');` and then parsing the summary could work too but screenscraping is evil.

Or read about analytic snapshots? If you can live with having the data slightly outdated and summary being saved in helper custom object (potentially wasting space) - you can then query that helper object instead, build other reports that are using it instead of summarizing thosands of rows of source data etc.